# allow previews outside wordpress folder (Outsourcing WP previews)

Tags: php, wp-query, previews, outside-wordpress

I am outsourcing the wordpress and I already figured out the external view. I even know how to make a WP query for previews, but when I want to do that I simply cant - wp-load stops all operations and I get something like "You do not have permission to preview drafts" - any idea what might cause that? (Its the same hosting, and I am correctly logged in.) - so my guess is that wordpress checks for some part of REQUEST_URI ?

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is the wordpress checking for his cookies - and cookies are different for each folder. So the way of fixing can be temporarily save WP cookies too session and then hardcode them after redirect before the WP load.

Solved thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542795/wordpress-allow-previews-outside-wordpress-folder